# Loop : print a word and delete one letter each time by iteration

Tags: python, loops

I'm looking for some help on an exercise.
Let's say I have to call a `variable = "house"` and the goal is by using the for loop, print the word and delete one letter each time using iteration.

The result expected is :

```
house
hous
hou
ho
h
```

This is what I've done :

```
variable = "house"

for i in range(len(variable)):
    print(variable[:-i])
```

But the result of that is

```
hous
hou
ho
h
```

Is there an astuce to print the first world "house" inside the loop ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do that:

```
variable = "house"

for i in range(len(variable)):
    print(variable)
    variable = variable[:-1]
```

Or with a while loop:

```
variable = "house"

while variable:
    print(variable)
    variable = variable[:-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
variable = "house"

for i in range(len(variable), 0, -1):
    print(variable[:i])
```